Is image upload broken right now?
I was having trouble uploading the load-bearing image for my Identifying games referenced in the banner for Hooded Horse publisher sale of 2024 question...
...but then I realised that, say, this old and upvoted answer is just a long string of "enter image description here", and trying to follow the i.sstatic.net link gives me:

oh no, that request didn't look right
RayID: 8c9a2c794876b33c

Is it a general issue?

Update: To further confound the issue, when I viewed my question about 2 hours later, both the uploaded original and its thumbnail are for me viewable normally, both embedded on SE and on the hosting site. The ones from the 2022 answer are still not, though.

Probably related: Mostly unable to see images on Stack Exchange sites

Yes, I also only see a sequence of "enter image description here" and no images.

I cannot reproduce any issues.
